# how recognize on which bot reply we got answer

Tags: c#, botframework

Bot generate multiple questions using backdoor events from webchat in sequence
 without getting answer from user. Below example for two questions :

```
 //Question 1
 var reply = ((Activity)activity).CreateReply("Question 1");
 reply.Type = ActivityTypes.Message;
 reply.TextFormat = TextFormatTypes.Plain;

 reply.SuggestedActions = new SuggestedActions()
 {
      Actions = new List<CardAction>()
                   {
                        new CardAction() {Title = "Ans 1", Type = ActionTypes.ImBack, Value = "Ans 1"},
                        new CardAction() {Title = "Ans 2", Type = ActionTypes.ImBack, Value = "Ans 2"}
                     }
                };
 await connectorClient.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);   


 //Question 2 after 10 sec
 var reply = ((Activity)activity).CreateReply("Question 2");
 reply.Type = ActivityTypes.Message;
 reply.TextFormat = TextFormatTypes.Plain;

 reply.SuggestedActions = new SuggestedActions()
 {
      Actions = new List<CardAction>()
                   {
                        new CardAction() {Title = "Ans 1", Type = ActionTypes.ImBack, Value = "Ans 1"},
                        new CardAction() {Title = "Ans 2", Type = ActionTypes.ImBack, Value = "Ans 2"}
                     }
                };
 await connectorClient.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
```

How to recognize in receiving Activity activity on what question user answered- on Question 1 or Question 2?

Comment: You probably need to supply unique values for each CardAction. The user should only see the titles anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this is very simple, all you need to do Is make the `Value` parameter unique.  In code, it would look like the snippet below.  You may also want to consider using `ActionTypes.PostBack` rather than `ActionTypes.ImBack`  that way the user does not actually see the `Value`

```
var connectorClient = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
                var reply = ((Activity)activity).CreateReply("Question 1");
                reply.Type = ActivityTypes.Message;
                reply.TextFormat = TextFormatTypes.Plain;

                reply.SuggestedActions = new SuggestedActions()
                {
                    Actions = new List<CardAction>()
                    {
                        new CardAction() {Title = "Ans 1", Type = ActionTypes.PostBack, Value = "question 1 Ans 1"},
                        new CardAction() {Title = "Ans 2", Type = ActionTypes.PostBack, Value = "question 1 Ans 2"}
                    }
                };
                await connectorClient.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);


                //Question 2 after 10 sec
                reply = ((Activity)activity).CreateReply("Question 2");
                reply.Type = ActivityTypes.Message;
                reply.TextFormat = TextFormatTypes.Plain;

                reply.SuggestedActions = new SuggestedActions()
                {
                    Actions = new List<CardAction>()
                    {
                        new CardAction() {Title = "Ans 1", Type = ActionTypes.PostBack, Value = "question 2 Ans 1"},
                        new CardAction() {Title = "Ans 2", Type = ActionTypes.PostBack, Value = "question 2 Ans 2"}
                    }
                };
                await connectorClient.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
```